# If X,Y,Z are i.i.d standard normal random variables, then is XY and YZ independent?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, independence

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d standard normal random variables.
Is XY and YZ independent? My guess is no, but I am looking for a formal proof.

**Current thinking**:

1. I tried to see whether I could show that $f_{XY,YZ}(a,b)=f_{XY}(a)f_{YZ}(b)$. So far I have
   \begin{align*}
   f_{XY,YZ}(a,b)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY,YZ|Y=y}(a,b|Y=y)f_{Y}(y)dy \\
   &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(\frac{a}{y})f_Z(\frac{b}{y})f_Y(y)dy \\
   \end{align*}
   Unfortunately, substituting in the expressions for the density of a standard normal gives an integrand which cannot be integrated (by calculators). So it seems like looking for an expression for the joint density isn't going to work.
2. The covariance of XY and YZ is zero, so we can't immediately conclude that XY and YZ are dependent.
3. My guess is that the answer is no, since intuitively if XY is a large value might then this might suggest that Y is large, which may suggest that YZ is large (at least in magnitude). But I do not know whether this is something that we can work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$
\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = 1\cdot 1 = 1
$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2]\mathbb{E}[(YZ)^2] = 1. \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
However,
$$
\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2(YZ)^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2Y^4Z^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^4]\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = 1\cdot 3\cdot 1 = 3 \tag{$\ddagger$}
$$
and so $(XY)^2$ and $(YZ)^2$ are not independent. Can you conclude?

Comment: The idea is to look at $(XY)^2$ and $(YZ)^2$ to avoid the covariance-zero issue we have with $XY$ and $YZ$.